# How do I unzip multiple files?

Tags: powershell, zip, unzip

I am attempting to loop through zip files in a folder and extract them. I am receiving a null error for the `zip.items()`. How could this value be null?

When I `Write-Host $zip` the value that is posted is `System.__ComObject`.

```
$dira = "D:\User1\Desktop\ZipTest\IN"
$dirb = "D:\User1\Desktop\ZipTest\DONE\" 

$list = Get-childitem -recurse $dira -include *.zip

$shell = new-object -com shell.application

foreach($file in $list)
{
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($dirb).copyhere($file)
    }
    Remove-Item $file
}
```

The error message I am receiving is:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  
At D:\Users\lr24\Desktop\powershellunziptest2.ps1:12 char:29  
+     foreach($item in $zip.items <<<< ())
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (items:String) [], RuntimeException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Please show the actual code you're running (not something you fabricated or typed from memory) as well as the complete error you're getting.

Comment: i have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$file` is a `FileInfo` object, but the [`NameSpace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method expects either a string with a full path or a numeric constant. Also, you need to copy `$item`, not `$file`.

Change this:

```
foreach($file in $list)
{
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($dirb).copyhere($file)
    }
    Remove-Item $file
}
```

into this:

```
foreach($file in $list)
{
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.FullName)
    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($dirb).copyhere($item)
    }
    Remove-Item $file
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw that the full name wasn't being used and found a solution a few minutes ago using the full name in the get-childitem cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 7-zip in your $env:path

```
PS> $zips = dir *.zip
PS> $zips | %{7z x $_.FullName}

#unzip with Divider printed between unzip commands
PS> $zips | %{echo "`n`n======" $_.FullName; 7z x $_.FullName}
```

you can get 7-zip here:

```
http://www.7-zip.org/

PS> $env:path += ";C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip"
```

Explanation:

Percent followed by curly braces is called the foreach operator: %{ }
This operator means that "Foreach" object in the pipe, the code in the curly braces is called with the object placed in the "$_" variable.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the shell initialization.

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
```

use it before the NameSpace.

Comment: I left it out of the post above by mistake but it is in my code and i am still receiving the error.

Comment: instead of `$zip.items()`, try `$zip[i]` in a for loop.

Comment: I gave that a shot.  It returned:   Missing or invalid array index expression.  At line 10 position 24.